# GRAILS : <g:layoutTitle> does not work

Tags: java, grails, tags

I want to create layout for my grails application based on this tutorial:
http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-layout-templates

I create a page.gsp with the skeleton of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <style>
    #header {background-color:#ffe0e0;text-align: center;}
    #footer {background-color:#e0e0ff;text-align: center;}
    </style>
    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">HEADER</div>

    <g:layoutBody/>
    <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And mainpage.gsp with main content:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="page"/>
        <title>I am a test page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Test page.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Page is mapped in UrlMappings.groovy:

```
"/"(view:'/layouts/page')
```

But when I try to run my project I always got the error message like this:

> URI/
>   Class java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Message
>   Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/layouts/page.gsp:4] Error executing tag : [views/layouts/page.gsp:4] Error executing tag : null
>   Caused by
>   null

Without    it works properly.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT display the decorator pages directly (out of `grails-app/views/layouts` dir). The purpose of those is to decorate OTHER pages.

So, instead of the nonsense like

```
"/"(view:'/layouts/page')
```

you should be using smth like:

```
"/"(view:'/mainpage')
```

so that your `mainpage.gsp` is decorated by `layouts/page.gsp`.